# How to make Redirect Extension

Tags: commerce, redirection

I am creating website which will redirect to the user/login before to see the content since I am using [Anonymous Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/anonymous_redirect) module.

Also, I'm using the [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module, so with that, I have one problem. When I want to checkout anonymously, it redirects me to the login page. How can I extend this checkout process to add product before login?

**Example:** When I add "example.com/product/someproduct" it's redirecting me to the login page without checkout button, cant see the products.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the module to Required Login and repair my problems, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Note that since you are requiring that anonymous traffic not see content, then product pages would be protected as well, making anonymous checkout impossible without some monkeying. You would likely need to bypass the anonymous redirect on product pages OR create a url that passes a product id to the anonymous user's cart (it would create one if it doesn't exist) and then redirects to the checkout. This would be possible with a rule running on bootstrap, but does have performance implications.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Rn7FLFytTU is the video where I walk you through this using rules.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Checkout login step](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_login_step) module to provide option for without login.

Comment: the problem is, then i add "example.com/product/someproduct" it redirecting me to the login page without checkout button, cant see the products

Comment: you mean when you go to `example.com/product/someproduct` it redirects you to the login, so you can't see the product page until you login?